# Error installing python-docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, python-docx

Trying to install python-docx through pip for 'Learn to Automate the Boring Things with Python'. I am getting errors like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAZhK.jpg).

I have Googled up some solutions to this issue, but they don't seem to work for me, or I am not deploying the solution correctly.

One post on Stackoverflow said to download an lxml file made available by [Christoph Golke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml).

I downloaded, and then tried 'pip install lxml', and basically got the same error message as the screenshot, telling me 'Unable to find vcvarsall.bat'.

Am I supposed to put this file in a certain directory, before executing that command? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: type `pip install --upgrade pip` ... then try and reinstall lxml when you get the error it will have a url listed in the error message ... go to the url listed and download the C++ redistributable that will allow you to install the package in question ... rerun `pip install lxml` and it should nnow build

Comment: Do I need to have the lxml I downloaded in a specific directory? Or can I just execute the `pip install lxml`, after downloading the C++ redistributable? @JoranBeasley

Comment: @JoranBeasley So I tried doing as you said. I upgraded, which worked fine. Then I downloaded the lxml file from the site listed in my post. Then I placed it in the directory that my command prompt was on (c:\users\myName\). Then I did the command `pip install lxml`. Then [this](http://imgur.com/a/6kyge) is the result I got...any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I found the answer to this issue.

So I wasn't aware that to install the lxml file, you first need to change to the directory of that file, and type in the **complete name** of that file. Either that, or typing the path of the lxml file directly into the cmd prompt, like:

```
pip install C:\Users\yourName\Downloads\lxml-3.6.4-cp35-cp35m-win32
```

or

```
cd C:\Users\yourName\Downloads
pip install lxml-3.6.4-cp35-cp35m-win32
```

which successfully installed the lxml file, which then led to a successful installation of the python-docx file.

Essentially, a basic knowledge of the command prompt would've helped me avoid this problem...but hope this helps for anyone else who doesn't know what to do!

Answer (score 1):

This mean that C++ Common Tools are not installed.
To install them for Python2.7 go to [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)
For python3 install `Visual Studio Community 2015` and execute the following command:

```
SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS140COMNTOOLS%
```

Comment: Silly question, but is there any way to download the C++ Common Tools without downloading another IDE?

Comment: So I installed Visual Studio Community 2015, and afterwardstried installing the module again. Didn't work. Same error.

Comment: @PhillipChoi Try executing `SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS140COMNTOOLS%`.